# Железо MacBook Pro 2010 г ,возможно ли установить Catalin

Tags: xcode, macos, macbook

Не подскажите как я могу установить на macbook pro 2010 года Catalin до этого стоит High Sierra Мои параметры Macbook pro 15 inch mid 2010 Processor 2.66Ghz Intel core i7, 4 gb озу,видюха Nvidea GeForce GT330  512mb ,intel hd graphics 288mb. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Просто если смотреть по документации я не могу поставить Catalin потому что не подерживается
 https://support.apple.com/ru-ru/HT210222

А если посмотреть на avito там такой же ноутбук и говорят что можно подставить Catalin
https://www.avito.ru/novosibirsk/noutbuki/apple_macbook_pro_15_core_i7_8gb_500gb_hdd_1864816606

Вопрос вообще на мой мас с такими параметрами можно поставить Сatalin c последним Xcode 11.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Здесь](https://appleinsider.ru/macbook/kak-ustanovit-macos-catalina-na-nepodderzhivaemye-mac.html) пишут, что установить можно, если осторожно, с помощью [патчера](http://dosdude1.com/catalina/), но нет гарантии, что все будет работать как надо, так что если вы решили поверить продавцу и купить данный макбук в надежде на успех, то стоит хорошо подумать, возможно стоило бы попросить продавца сначала установить Каталину и предъявить доказательства успешной работы, но и здесь все равно остается пространство для введения в заблуждение